# Spring data - MongoDB : How to return a page/slice of only specific fields

Tags: mongodb, performance, spring-data

I want to implement pagination with scroll.  My goal is to get a slice of data when scroll event is triggered.

My document "Foo" structure is relatively complex with a lot of nested objects. But I need to show only two fields from these documents.

I have two questions:

- In general, is specifying the fields in the query will enhance the performance? 
  (seing that we dont get the whole document)

for example:

```
    @Query(value="{ path : ?0}", fields="{ path : 0 }")
    List<Foo> findByPath(String path);
```

- If yes, How can I get a slice of documents with specific fields using "Pagebale"

  ```
     Slice<Foo> findSliceBy(Pageable pageable);
  ```

Comment: you can add Pageable attribute to any query.

Answer (score 0):

When specifying the fields the performance is enhanced.

Just annotating the findSliceBy method with  @Query will do the job

```
    @Query(fields="{path:1, name:1}")
   Slice<Foo> findSliceBy(Pageable pageable);
```